# How should I parse URL parameters using Node JS express?

Tags: node.js

I would like to pass the lat lon from this URL http://localhost:8080/fp?lon=103.742463567216646&lat=1.336711421273283. Where should I place the "req.query.lon" and "req.query.lat" in the following code?

I am hoping to parse the users input in the URL link so that I can dynamically retrieve from the database.

```
const {Client} = require("pg")
const express = require ("express")
const url=require('url')
const fs= require('')
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

const client = new Client({
    "user": "xxx",
    "password" : "xxx",
    "host" : "xxx",
    "port" : xxx,
    "database" : "xxx"
})

//app.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`))

app.get("/fp", async (req, res) => {
    //const lon = 103.742463567216646;
    //const lat = 1.336711421273283;
    //const lon = req.query.lon;
    //const lat = req.query.lat;
    const rows = await readTodos ();

    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
})





app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Web server is listening.. on port 8080"))

start()

async function start() {
    await connect();


}


async function connect() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(`Failed to connect ${e}`)
    }
}

async function readTodos() {
    try {
    const results = await client.query("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(geom)) FROM fp ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+lon+ ","+lat+ "), 3993) LIMIT 1;");
    return results.rows;
    }
    catch(e){
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: The place you have commented is the correct code. You can have them there, pls uncomment them and it works

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for help with.  If you are properly passing the URL as shown in your question, then the `req.query.lon` and `req.query.lat` are the right way to access query parameters on that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express parses it by default and store them in `req.query`.
Accessing `req.query.<key>` will give you the value you are looking for.
For instance, in your example, express will store it inside `req.query.lon` and `req.query.lat`.
So, actually you access them right in the request handler of `/fp`, just comment out the access to these variables and pass them as parameters to `readTodos()`:

```js
app.get("/fp", async (req, res) => {
    const lon = req.query.lon;
    const lat = req.query.lat;
    const rows = await readTodos(lon, lat);

    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
})

async function readTodos(lon, lat) {
    try {
    const results = await client.query("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force2D(geom)) FROM fp ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("+lon+ ","+lat+ "), 3993) LIMIT 1;");
    return results.rows;
    }
    catch(e){
        return [];
    }
}
```